# kendoUI TabStrip selection fire another button event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-tabstrip

I have a Kendo Tabstrip in a web form. There I have functionality which fires another button when we change tab selection. Actually it calls the server method and brings back some information.

I know we can achieve this by using an AJAX call, however my client wants a full post back.

Here is the example..

```
http://jsfiddle.net/schngupta/G3mjv/2/
```

example code:

```
var data = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    select: tabSelect
}).data('kendoTabStrip');

function tabSelect(e) {
    if (confirm("Clicking OK will again click below button.")) { 
        $("#btn").click();
    }
    else
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function called()
{
    alert("hi")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in JSFiddle the script section is executed after document load. If you put your script in onload event (as in fiddle demo) you should attach the click event handler to the button with JavaScript. Otherwise if you want to use the onclick attribute to the html element define `called` function outside the onload event.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3mjv/4/)